# Stop Sphinx server

Tags: sphinx

I'm using Sphinx search server(version 'Sphinx 2.0.3-id64-release (r3043)' from http://sphinxsearch.com/) in my Rails app with thinking_sphinx gem. Sphinx starts automatically when I reboot and I can't stop it. I tried `sudo searchd --stop` but the process just respawns itself.

Comment: on CentOS 7 `killall searchd` if it's started as a process, not as a service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop (as manual start too) requires --config parameter.

If you start sphinx with command `searchd --config=file`, you can stop it with `searchd --config=file --stop`. Try to determine your start command argument.

P.S. Better late than never :)

You can also send a signal kill -9

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using it anymore but hope that helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

searchd expects signal TERM to be stopped. searchd --config /path/to/config --stop just sends TERM to the pid specified in 'pidfile' in the config. 
'kill ' or 'killall searchd' will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Currently to stop Sphinx in Debian:

```
sudo service sphinxsearch stop
```

To verify status:

```
sudo service sphinxsearch status
```

To start:

```
sudo service sphinxsearch start
```